# selinux-policy update prevents ssh into ec2. Now what?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, selinux, centos7

I created a new EC2 instance using the official CentOS 7 (x86_64) HVM image.

I ran:

```
yum upgrade
```

At:

```
Running transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
  Updating   : 32:bind-license-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.noarch                                                                       1/80
  Updating   : selinux-policy-3.12.1-153.el7_0.13.noarch                                                                     2/80
```

I can no longer SSH into the box :-(

I can establish a connection on port 22, but see nothing more after that running ssh client in verbose mode.

I guess mounting the [EBS on another instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598) is my only means of recovery.

If I do that, what's the easiest way to restore ssh access?  I'm not sure whether that update set selinux to enforcing, and whether that would even be [the issue here](http://bugs.centos.org/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=4959)?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again ...

Comment: Actually, that helped! I noticed that prior to restart, the AWS console said "Instance reachability check failed". I thought that fix-by-rebooting only worked for Windows ;-)

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped.